# how to display data in gridview from existing tables

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to display the details in `Gridview` by using existing table data, suppose i have `3 
tables` .i.e **Tables_Name:** `Studentdetails, Class, Section`.

I want to display StudentId,StudentName,ClassName,Section in another table gridview,

Comment: Wut u tried so far ? code pls ? **Tip:** Made a select query joining your tables and fill Dataset later bind your GridView with DataSet.tables[0]

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource will need to be based on some query that joins the data from those three tables (can they be joined?), from there you just populate the gridview with the resulting dataset. It's hard to give any more of a detailed answer without more detail I'm afraid.